# Requirements for entering Switzerland

Tags: visas, schengen, switzerland

Currently I'm studying in Poland and I have the following visa:

1. Visa for Etats Schengen
2. Type C
3. Single entry
4. Remarks: Ecole/ Etudes R/PL VIS

The visa was issued by the Swiss embassy.

My question is: Can I enter Switzerland with the present visa or do I need a special visa?

Comment: Switzerland is part of the Schengen area so a C Schengen visa should be perfectly fine. Furthermore, if you are in Poland, you are already in the Schengen area and your passport will not be stamped on the way to Switzerland. But I am a bit surprised by your question. What's your status in Poland? Do you have a Polish visa as well? Are you going to study in Switzerland? Where and why did you apply for a Swiss visa?

Comment: I have seen many questions on this site, but this is by far the most confusing.

Comment: Think of Schengen area as a big country and think of member states as cities of that big country, you are granted access to that big country so visiting cities within that big country is granted by default.

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: Perhaps it should be added that on single entry visa, flight connections via non-Schengen countries should/must be avoided. Sometimes, they can be the cheapest.

Comment: I'm going to put that on hold since the OP did not return to answer the question about his/her nationality.